# Selenium Python - StaleElementReferenceException Error

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, staleelementreferenceexception

Currently I am practicing using selenium for Web Scraping and encountering StaleElementReferenceException Error. I tried to scrap the phone information from a retailed website and tried to make it for 3 pages. I used a for loop and it worked fine for the 1st page. Then I encountered the error. I have tried WebDriverWait, time.sleep, etc. but it didn't work. Please help me with this. Below is my code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('https://tiki.vn/')

category = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//a[@title='Điện Thoại - Máy Tính Bảng']").click()

phone_information = []
for page in range(1,4):
    next_page = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//a[@data-view-label="{}"]'.format(page)).get_attribute('href')
    driver.get(next_page)
    element = (By.XPATH, '//div[@class="inner"]')
    WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(element))
    phone_names = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH , '//div[@class="info"]')
    for phone in phone_names:
        print(phone.text)

WebDriverWait(driver, 60)

driver.quit()
```

This is the output:

```
StaleElementReferenceException            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[7], line 16
     14     time.sleep(10)
     15     for phone in phone_names:
---> 16         print(phone.text)
     17     time.sleep(20)
     19 WebDriverWait(driver, 60)
```

Comment: The code in the error does not match the posted code.  Please post your real code.

Comment: Hi @JohnGordon, that's my actual code. I used jupyter to work with in this practice. First cell was the packages that are needed to import. It would be:
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

The second cell was the posted code

Comment: @JohnGordon, I have tried WebDriverWait, time.sleep, etc. but it didn't work, so I dropped them out of the code.

Comment: _so I dropped them out of the code_ Okay, so please run the actual code and post the actual error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### TL;DR

Just enclose it in a `try-catch` block and re-find the element. Quick and dirty solution. Error-prone.

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException # import the exception type
 // ...
    for phone in phone_names:
        try:
            print(phone.text)
        except StaleElementReferenceException:
            element = (By.XPATH, '//div[@class="inner"]')
            WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(element))
            phone_names = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH , '//div[@class="info"]')
            continue
// ...
```

#### Further intuition into why you get that error

Hi. The problem is that the *reference* to the `element` you created when calling `find_element()` is pointing to an element that not longer present in the DOM. Note that the `CSS.Selector` or `XPATH` that you pass to describe *the structure* of an element is distinct from the element per se. As stated in [Selenium's docs for the WebDriver API](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException), the error you're getting:

> **exception**
> *selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException(msg:
>
> Optional[str] = None, screen: Optional[str] = None, stacktrace:
>
> Optional[Sequence[str]] = None)*
> **Bases:**
> `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException`
>
> Thrown when a reference to an element is now “stale”.
>
> Stale means the element no longer appears on the DOM of the page.
>
> Possible causes of StaleElementReferenceException include, but not
> limited to:
>
> - You are no longer on the same page, or the page may have
>   refreshed since the element was located.
> - The element may have been
>   removed and re-added to the screen, since it was located. Such as an
>   element being relocated.
> - Element may
>   have been inside an iframe or another context which was refreshed.

#### Approach to solution

Althought a more robust solution cuold be achieved with some refactorig, *knowing* that the problem is in the reference provides you with the insight that you should only look up the element again and it should work fine. You've stated that the problem occurs when refreshing, and as you haven't provided the relevant HTML I'll just assume that the XPATH for the new `element` stays the same.

To make this easier to work with we should try to divide the task in it's constituent parts. *i.e.* finding the element, and then operating over it. We know the exception is raised in the finding bits.  Furthermore, as long as the element you are finding is the `phone_names` collection and not each `phone` per se, you don't need to check for every `phone`, just the collection.

```
def print_phones(phone_names_element):
    for phone in phone_names_element:
        print(phone.text)

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('https://tiki.vn/')

category = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//a[@title='Điện Thoại - Máy Tính Bảng']").click()

phone_information = []
for page in range(1,4):
    next_page = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//a[@data-view-label="{}"]'.format(page)).get_attribute('href')
    driver.get(next_page)
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="inner"]'))
    phone_names = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH , '//div[@class="info"]')
    try:
        print_phones(phone_names_element)
    except StaleElementReferenceException:
        continue

WebDriverWait(driver, 60)

driver.quit()
```

^^^^^^^^^^
In the above code snippet i've extracted the `print_phones` functionality, I've inlined the `element`'s bits (as `.until()` returns the element) and I've enclosed the call in a try loop as to avoid stale references.

Notes:

- you could replaces your `sleep` calls and explicity time waits with a driver configurated [`ìmplicit wait`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#implicit-waits)
- it would prove useful to replce some of the magic numers and strings for a more declarative and programatic approach so you can easly identify bugs and further develop your srcipt.

Hope it helps.

Comment: _pointing to an element that not longer present in the DOM_ Why would that be, when the element was the result of a `find_elements()` call **immediately before** the for loop?  I don't see why the DOM would have changed.

Comment: It seems weird to me too @JohnGordon. But given the exception that's being raised is clear that the WebDriver is getting a *stale* reference. As OP stated that the code, as is, runs and prints before a page reload my best guess is that the site he's trying to scrappe has a pretty intesive bunch of client-side JS, probably made with an obese framework, that's messing the state of the page, the DOM, and refreshing elements and what not. A lot could have changed from one statement to another. A poorly written event emitter, o any piece of generated JS could be the culprit.

Comment: Honestly, as the task is to extract text from a webpage using Python, I'd probably just GET the relevant HTML from the pages and parse them. Maybe use BS4 if the DOM tree is particularly obscure. Emulating a human interacting with a browser is a shared-state nightmare prone to this kind of weird-ass errors.

Comment: Hi @HernanATN, thank you for your support. It worked now for both the codes.

Comment: Great to hear. Good Luck

Comment: oh hi @HernanATN, can I ask you again? I just tried your codes again but this time it thrown me an error on **name 'StaleElementReferenceException' is not defined**.
```NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[21], line 20
     18     try:
     19         print_phones(phone_names)
---> 20     except StaleElementReferenceException:
     21         continue
     23 WebDriverWait(driver, 60)

NameError: name 'StaleElementReferenceException' is not defined
```
Sometimes it works, sometimes it gives me that error. I could not understand why.

Comment: Oh I see, my bad. I should have mentioned to import that specific Exception type. Just add `from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException`

Comment: @HernanATN I just change the range from getting 3 pages to 27 pages, and it gave me the error.

Comment: @NguyễnThànhĐạt I've edited the answer to include the import

Comment: @HernanATN thank you so much. It finally worked well now. Many thanks again